# delete Pandas df row using mask, based on the last letter of a string column

Tags: python, pandas, mask

For example, in the pandas dataframe below with 3 rows, all of which are strings.
I wanna drop based on condition `if str[-1] == '-':`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ["123-","123-1","123-2"]})
```

But if I do

```
df[df['a'][-1]=='-']
```

It will return an error. I know it's possible to do it with df.apply function. But I am just wondering if it can be done with mask.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create the mask using a regular expression as below. The dollar sign will ensure the hyphen is only matched at the end of the string.

```
df.a.str.contains('-$')
```

This will return a boolean series. Using your example:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
```

You can then drop the rows as usual using `df.drop()`:

```
df.drop(df[df.a.str.contains('-$')].index, inplace=True)
```

And reset the index if you would like:

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Comment: Wouldn't `df.index[df.a.str.contains('-$')]` be more efficient than `df[df.a.str.contains('-$')].index`?

Comment: This worked for me, and also if you get `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values` add `na=False` to your `.str.contains`